# SQL Server - Change AuditLevel on Linux hosted instance

Tags: linux, audit, sql-server-2019

just wondering if it's possible to change the AuditLevel on SQL Server 15.0.1800.32 (2019) hosted on Linux to "Failed logins only".

Currently it's set to audit failed and successful logins and I would really like to switch it to failed only.

Many thanks in advance!